# Get the current js file path which is inserted dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have created a `<script>` tag in an http://example.com/index.html tag using javascript like

```
 (function() {
            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
            script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://example2.com/xyz/def/internal.js");
            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    })();
```

Now inside this internal.js file i want to get its file path "http://example2.com/xyz/def/"

Comment: You don't need to use `.setAttribute()` to set those properties, and you don't need to set the "type" property at all. Just `script_tag.src = "...";` will work.

Comment: @pointy Okay, btw it was not what i asked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @A1rPun No, here the script is created via js itself, so it may not probably be the last script created.

Comment: @void it will be the last `<script>` tag in the document when it's added, because the other ones won't have been seen yet.

Comment: No the current script will be the script tag itself not the js file.

Comment: Yes. Thats where I am stuck.

Comment: There are other possibilities in some of the more recent answers in the linked question. If all else fails, you can always just put the script path in a global variable, since the code that *loads* it certainly knows the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Inside internal.js

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    script = scripts[scripts.length - 1], url = "";
if (script.getAttribute.length !== undefined) {
   url = script.src;
}
else
{
   url = script.getAttribute('src', -1);
}
```

With modern browsers this should work

```
url = document.currentScript.src;
```

Comment: It wont work, because scripts[scripts.length - 1] will return the <script> tag not the js file.